# Jmeter functions don't executing when calling from java code

Tags: java, function, jmeter

I'm using some jmeter functions in my jmx file. 
When I run it from command line with jmeter tool, its running normally, executing the function and return a value.

When I run the java code , which load the same jmx file its taking a function as a string and don't return a value.

I have tested with several functions, Results are the same.
In jtl file I see something like this- ${__time(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)}

```
<httpSample t="663" it="0" lt="631" ts="1492989803759" s="true" lb="User-getapikey   ${__time(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)} " rc="200" rm="" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" de="UTF-8" by="528" ng="1" na="1">
```

Its my java code, its working normally when I don't have a functions:

```
StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterPropertiesPath);
JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHomePath);
JMeterUtils.initLogging();
JMeterUtils.initLocale();

SaveService.loadProperties();
HashTree testPlanTree = null;
                try{
                    log.info("loading testPlanTree");
                    testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(jmxFile);
                    JMeter.convertSubTree( testPlanTree );
                }catch(IOException ex){
                    log.info("error loading file as tree");
                    log.info(ex.getMessage());
                    return;
                }
                jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
                jmeter.run();
```

Comment: Could you please mention the error that you got?

Comment: I am having this exact same issue as well. Was there any resolution to this?

Comment: Yes @DanielIsrael instaed of running command:
CMD = "/java/bin/java -jar /test/test.jar "

we run command: 
CMD = "/java/bin/java -cp '/test/test.jar:/test/test_lib/*' com.company.JmeterPlugin "

test_lib contains all our jars included ApacheJMeter_functions.jar

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good, just **double check you have `ApacheJMeter_functions.jar` in your project classpath**. The file is located under "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation.

You might also want to add [ResultCollector](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/ResultCollector.html) to store your test execution results into .jtl file like:

```
Summariser summer = null;
String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
    summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
}

ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
logger.setFilename("result.jtl");
testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);
```

Check out [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) for more information on different approaches to JMeter test execution including using Java API to kick off and develop tests.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your answer, I have tried a lot of things during this period. Its working normal when I include ApacheJMeter_functions.jar as a external jar to my project classpath, and run application as a java application. I'm getting normal results in my jtl.
But when I'm exporting it to .jar, and call it from command line, its didn't understand that ApacheJMeter_functions.jar is included.

Comment: I have added it to classpath in meta-inf, also tried to put 
`JMeterUtils.setProperty("search_paths", "JMeter_lib/ApacheJMeter_functions.jar");`
with relative and absolute paths, but its continue to skip my function call.
 Also I have tried the codes from link that you have provided, but its also don't working when I run it as  a jar.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? i am also facing this issue