# Jmeter random function is not working from java application

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I want to make use of Jmeter Random function `(${__RandomString(10,0123456789,Value)})` in my java application for load testing.

### Below is maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_functions</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It is working properly If I add `ApacheJMeter_functions` jar to class path but the same is not working if I use Maven dependency.

Note : Works fine if I add jar to classpath without version name.

pom :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>performance-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_functions</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[Response when added ApacheJMeter_functions jar to class path without version name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYtjq.png)

[Response when added ApacheJMeter_functions dependency jar into pom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md1Bj.png)

Comment: How does your pom.xml look ? What error do you get in your IDE ?

Comment: @FrancescoIannazzo It also works fine if I rename the jar in maven repo from ApacheJMeter_functions.4.0.jar to ApacheJMeter_functions.jar.So is there any way we can rename the dependency jar and add it to maven repository ?

Answer (score 2):

Below solution helped me in resolving issue

When Jmeter functions are used in the Java code, Jmeter tries to compare the function related classes from java class path with classes from the **'search_path'** *(Reads classes from the jars)*. So Jmeter function works only if required function class is present in both the path *(Jmeter has seperate class for each function)*.

This is why we need to make sure the 'ApacheJMeter_functions' jar added in the pom *(which will be added in class path )* and the path to jmeter functions jar is set to **'search_path'**.Both should have same version.

But in case of spring boot application, along adding dependency to pom we also need to append the path to jmeter functions jar explicitly to the class path like below

```
System.setProperty("java.class.path", System.getProperty("java.class.path") + PathToJmeterFunctionJars );
```