# Using User Parameter Pre Processor for ${__UUID()} function in Jmeter doesn't work while executing the jmx script from Maven framework

Tags: maven, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am calling the ${__UUID()} function in my script to generate UUID, using User Parameter pre processor.
[image: UserParameter]

This ${__UUID()} works fine, and generates UUID when I execute the jmx script from Jmeter gui or Jmeter non gui/cmd.

Jmeter Log:
2020-04-14 15:24:44,173 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: UUID=======>3c8114da-1657-4e99-85bd-49081be0172b

But, whenever I am trying to execute this same jmx script from my JMeter-Maven framework, it only fails in the request using this function ${__UUID()}.

Jmeter Log:
2020-04-14 15:03:05,695 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: UUID=======>${__UUID()}

According to my understanding, based on the logs, its not able to generated the UUID using the function ${__UUID()}, while executing the script from JMeter-Maven framework.

Error Generated in HTML Report for the request using function ${__UUID()}: 
Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException/Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in query at index 43

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>JMeterMavenImpletation</groupId>
<artifactId>JMeterMaven</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>JMeterMaven</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_http -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_components -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_components</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_functions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_functions</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lazerycode.jmeter/jmeter-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- This goal will run the load test and generate the HTML report -->
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <!-- This goal runs some verification on error rate and fails the build -->
                <!-- <execution> <id>check-results</id> <phase>verify</phase> <goals> 
                    <goal>results</goal> </goals> </execution> -->
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!-- JVM Metrics -->
                <jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m</argument>
                        <argument>-Xmx1024m</argument>
                        <argument>-Xms1024m</argument>
                        <argument>-Xprof</argument>
                        <argument>-Xfuture</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                <!-- Test Script Properties -->
                <propertiesUser>
                    <users>${users}</users>
                    <rampup>${rampup}</rampup>
                    <loop>${loop}</loop>
                </propertiesUser>
                <!-- Fetching Test Script -->
                <testFilesIncluded>
                    <jMeterTestFile>${jMeterScriptFile}</jMeterTestFile>
                </testFilesIncluded>
                <!-- Time stamp -->
                <testResultsTimestamp>true</testResultsTimestamp>
                <!-- HTML Reports -->
                <generateReports>true</generateReports>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.codecentric/jmeter-graph-maven-plugin -->
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-graph-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <inputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/20190808-Scripts_SampleScript.jtl</inputFile>
                <!-- Custom Graphs -->
                <graphs>
                    <graph>
                        <pluginType>ResponseTimesOverTime</pluginType>
                        <width>800</width>
                        <height>600</height>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/ActiveThreadsOverTime.png</outputFile>
                    </graph>
                    <graph>
                        <pluginType>HitsPerSecond</pluginType>
                        <width>800</width>
                        <height>600</height>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/BytesThroughputOverTime.png</outputFile>
                    </graph>
                    <graph>
                        <pluginType>TransactionsPerSecond</pluginType>
                        <width>800</width>
                        <height>600</height>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/ResponseCodesPerSecond.png</outputFile>
                    </graph>
                    <graph>
                        <pluginType>TransactionsPerSecond</pluginType>
                        <width>800</width>
                        <height>600</height>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/ResponseTimesDistribution.png</outputFile>
                    </graph>
                    <graph>
                        <pluginType>TransactionsPerSecond</pluginType>
                        <width>800</width>
                        <height>600</height>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/ResponseTimesOverTime.png</outputFile>
                    </graph>
                    <graph>
                        <pluginType>TransactionsPerSecond</pluginType>
                        <width>800</width>
                        <height>600</height>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/ResponseTimesPercentiles.png</outputFile>
                    </graph>
                    <graph>
                        <pluginType>TransactionsPerSecond</pluginType>
                        <width>800</width>
                        <height>600</height>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/ThroughputVsThreads.png</outputFile>
                    </graph>
                    <graph>
                        <pluginType>TransactionsPerSecond</pluginType>
                        <width>800</width>
                        <height>600</height>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/ResponseTimesVSThreads.png</outputFile>
                    </graph>
                    <graph>
                        <pluginType>TransactionsPerSecond</pluginType>
                        <width>800</width>
                        <height>600</height>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/TransactionsPerSecond.png</outputFile>
                    </graph>
                </graphs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I would really appreciate if someone may aid me to resolve it !

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue however I can see several other problems with your test:

1. The correct syntax for [__UUID() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) would be:

   ```
   ${__UUID}
   ```

   It's better to use [Functions Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) if you're uncertain regarding the proper syntax, check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/) article for more details.
2. This `<dependencies>` block is not necessary, [JMeter Maven plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) will download the relevant version of JMeter itself
3. According to JMeter Best Practices [you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider changing the JMeter plugins version to `3.0.0`
4. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). Moreover, you should not be inlining JMeter functions or variables into the script, you should be using `vars.get("sample_id")` instead where `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thank you for your suggestion. I was able to resolve the issues, following this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429778/when-running-jmeter-script-from-java-functions-and-properties-do-not-work