# JMeter Functions are not evaluating while running JMX files using Java

Tags: jmeter

I am running the JMeter Scripts (.jmx files) using Java code. But it doesn's evaluate any of the JMeter Functions. I have tried multiple approaches and nothing worked.

In the logs, i could see the JMeter Functions are not evaluated. Functions like ${__property()}, {__TestPlanName()}, ${__threadNum}, ${__javaScript()} are not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add ApacheJMeter_functions.jar to your classpath ?

If not , please do.

Otherwise, show more about your project.

Comment: I have added it into classpath also while running, but it didnt worked. I have built the Java JMeter project using Maven. All the JMeter dependencies i have added, but it is not honoring the ApacheJMeter_functions.jar.

Comment: I had found similar issue in another link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577953/jmeter-functions-dont-executing-when-calling-from-java-code     But there also no answer for this.